# I can't change the background color of my screen and frame using customtkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, customtkinter

```
from customtkinter import *
import tkinter


janela = CTk()

class Aplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.janela = janela
        self.tela()
        self.frames_Da_tela()
        janela.mainloop()

    def tela(self):
        self.janela.title('Cadastro de Clientes')
        self.janela.geometry('700x500')
        self.janela.configure(background='#446C65') # <------- does not change the window background color
        self.janela.resizable(True, True)
        self.janela.maxsize(width= 900, height= 700)
        self.janela.minsize(width= 500, height= 300)
```

even putting 'red' or any other color it doesn't change

```
    def frames_Da_tela(self):
        self.frame_1 = CTkFrame(master=self.janela, bg='446C65', border_width= 3, border_color='#ACACAC') # <---- bg does not change the frame background color
        self.frame_1.place(relx= 0.02, rely=0.02, relwidth= 0.96, relheight= 0.46)




Aplication()
```

just adding bg=446C65 it returns several errors, and when removed, it works normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `fg_color`:

** You also have a `#` missing in line 23

```
from customtkinter import *
import tkinter


janela = CTk()

class Aplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.janela = janela
        self.tela()
        self.frames_Da_tela()
        janela.mainloop()

    def tela(self):
        self.janela.title('Cadastro de Clientes')
        self.janela.geometry('700x500')
        self.janela.configure(fg_color='#446C65')
        self.janela.resizable(True, True)
        self.janela.maxsize(width= 900, height= 700)
        self.janela.minsize(width= 500, height= 300)
        
    def frames_Da_tela(self):
        self.frame_1 = CTkFrame(master=self.janela, fg_color='#446C65', border_width= 3, border_color='#ACACAC') 
        self.frame_1.place(relx= 0.02, rely=0.02, relwidth= 0.96, relheight= 0.46)




Aplication()
```

Here is a [link](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/windows/window) for the `CTk` documintation